# Flex 4.6 - Custom Item Renderer - HTML formatted text

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flex4.5, itemrenderer

How do you display HTML formatted text in a Spark custom item renderer (Actionscript)?

---

Sample Code:

The html content in `item.post_content` displays as plain text in the `IconItemRenderer messageFunction` snippet below (which is just the default generated code for Icon Item renderer):

```
<s:itemRenderer>
    <fx:Component>
        <s:IconItemRenderer iconField="iconField" 
iconWidth="64" iconHeight="64" labelField="post_title" messageFunction="getPost">
        <fx:Script>
                    <![CDATA[
                private function getPost(item:Object):String{
                    return item.post_content;
        }

                ]]>
                </fx:Script>
                </s:IconItemRenderer>
            </fx:Component>
        </s:itemRenderer>
```

Comment: sample of code will be more helpful

Comment: added, although i'm not sure if the code sample helps. i am just looking for a way to display html formatted data in list items.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom skin that does what you want.

P.S.: The message function is intended to be a callback provided at a higher level in the project, not a private method of the renderer.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS19f279b149e7481c698e85712b3011fe73-7fff.html in custom mobile skins, it says "You cannot use the htmlText property in mobile applications." - so not sure if this is the right method to use..

Comment: You didn't say mobile.  But I think that if you want html formatted text, you'll either need to use the htmlText property (but I'm thinking this is an mx only property perhaps), or you need to use the tlf based controls (which might be even heavier).